# Error with the random module when launching the telegram bot to the server

Tags: python, heroku, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm trying to run a bot on the Heroku server, but there are difficulties: The bot should start working after the command:

```
$ heroku ps:scale worker=1
```

But I get the following message:

```
»   Warning: heroku update available from 7.53.0 to 7.59.2.
Scaling dynos... !
 !    Couldn't find that process type (worker).
```

Earlier, in CMD, I prescribed:

```
$ git push heroku master
```

And I got the answer that everything is fine except:

```
remote:        ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement random (from versions: none)
remote:        ERROR: No matching distribution found for random
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
```

Please help me to sort out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Like many languages, Python ships with a standard library that includes a certain amount of basic functionality out of the box. Most of the dependencies in your requirements.txt file are included in this standard library. There is no need to install them yourself.
You may remove random module from requirement text file . This should work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).